# how to fix Undefined variable: project in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I need add comment box to My Laravel app. this is blade file for comment box in comments folder of view file
comments/form.blade.php

```
 <form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('projects.comments.create', $project->id) }}">
        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('comments') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <textarea name="comments" class="form-control" style="width:80%;" id="comment" rows="5" cols="5"></textarea>
            @if ($errors->has('comments'))
                <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('comments') }}</span>
            @endif
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Add Comment</button>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    </form>
</div>
```

and now I am going to include this file in to the show.blade.php file in tasks folder
tasks/show.blade.php

```
@include('comments.form')
```

this is My CommentController.php

```
public function postNewComment(Request $request, $id, Comment $comment)
    {
       $this->validate($request, [
            'comments'     => 'required|min:5',
        ]);

       $comment->comments       = $request->input('comments');
       $comment->project_id     = $id;
       $comment->user_id        = Auth::user()->id;
       $comment->save();

       return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'Comment posted successfully');
    }
```

and comment model

```
 public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

but got following error

```
Undefined variable: project (View: C:\Users\Lilan\Desktop\ratakaju\resources\views\comments\form.blade.php)
```

how to fix this problem?

Comment: Its because $project is undefined. write condition to check it at action of form whether $project is defined or not

Comment: Either redirect to list of project or with project data.

Comment: Did you get any value from `$project` object?

Comment: you have to provide `project` variable to your view `form.blade.php`

Comment: can you any body describe how to provide project variable in my form.blade.php

Comment: do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Your controller method shows a redirect back, but you haven't shown the controller method that serves the page. In that method, you'll need to pass `$project` to the view.